# How to customize Magento Invoice based on GST TAX

Tags: magento-1.9, tax, tax-class

In India, GST tax applied, how can we customize Magento invoice based on **GST TAX**

> Note: How to differentiate Tax based on shipping address like shipping
> address same state same city tax calculation value divided into CGST
> and SGST, and shipping address different state  tax calculation value
> applied into IGST

[image]

Note: **community moderators**:  I am not asked to mean everything, just ask about the idea.

Comment: Have you got any idea for this @rathinam

Answer (score 0):

Hi Refer to this article, follow the given steps to configure the GST tax rates
http://www.credevator.com/how-to-configure-gst-in-magento-2/

Answer (score 0):

```
Extensions List for GST tax rates
```

1. https://store.webkul.com/magento2-gst-extension.html
2. https://magecomp.com/magento-2-indian-gst.html
3. https://cedcommerce.com/magento-2-extensions/indian-gst-magento-2-extension
4. https://meetanshi.com/magento-2-indian-gst.html
5. https://marketplace.magento.com/catalogsearch/result/?q=gst